# UIView malfunction

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

Upon Creating A `UIView` inside of a page Controller I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

```
lazy var registerButton: UIButton = {

    let rButton = UIButton(type: .system)

     rButton.frame = CGRect(x: 210, y: 600, width: 100, height: 50)

    rButton.setTitle("REGISTER", for: .normal)
    rButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    rButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    rButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    rButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

    rButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    rButton.layer.borderWidth = 2

    rButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(regSegue), for: .touchUpInside)

    return rButton
}()
```

See Code Below Which is the result of a button press( button press code is above):

```
func regSegue() {
    let page = UIPageViewController()
    present(page, animated: true, completion: nil)
    page.view.backgroundColor = UIColor .white;

    // let loginInputContainerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 12, y: 225, width: 350, height: 200.00));

    let inputContainerView = UIView()
    inputContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    inputContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    inputContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    inputContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    // need x,y,width,height

    inputContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    inputContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    inputContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true

    inputContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true

    page.view.addSubview(inputContainerView)
}
```

Please help, I am lost!!!!????

Do i have to add it here?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // will allow me to put a image as my UI background instead of a color

    // will make sure background image scales to screen size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    UIImage(named: "BestBackground")?.draw(in: self.view.bounds)
    // self is the screen we are working on
    //view is there to specify the controller view or the view that the controller manages
    //bounds describes the views location and size 

    if let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(){
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }else{
        // debugging incase image isnt found
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        debugPrint("Image not available")
    }

   // will add subiviews to the screen
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    view.addSubview(registerButton)





}

//will give you white status bar
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    return .lightContent
}
```

}

Comment: Don't [delete your question and then repost it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092723/issue-with-uiview).

Comment: wont happen again

Answer (score 1):

You can't activate the constraints because you haven't added `inputContainerView` to the view hierarchy of `view`. In fact, you also don't add `page.view` to the view hierarchy of `view`. When your `regSegue` method returns, the `page` object, and its view, will be deallocated.

I don't know exactly what you intend to do here. You need to add `page.view` to the view hierarchy that contains `view` (perhaps as a subview of `view`), and add `inputContainerView` as a subview of `page.view`, before you can activate any constraints between `inputContainerView` and `view`.

Or maybe you are calling this `regSegue` method to perform a segue, and the page view controller is supposed to be the destination of the segue. If that's the case, you need to get the destination controller from the segue object, **not** create a new controller.

Comment: the regSegue does perform a segue and the page view controller is infact the destination of the segue. How do i get the destination of the controller

Comment: by the way i have done all this programatically not using a story board

Comment: How did you create the segue if you are not using a storyboard?

Comment: i just created that function that triggers when a button is pressed

Comment: That doesn't sound like a segue. A segue is a connection created between two view controllers in a storyboard. You should edit your question to include the definition of your “function that triggers when a button is pressed”. You might also need to work through a tutorial on presenting view controllers programmatically.

Comment: Having read your updated question, I see that you need to learn how to present a view controller (your page view controller) or how to add a child view controller. You can find tutorials using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add inputContainerView to the page.view as a subview and then activate the constraints.

Comment: Note that the constraints aren't to `page.view`. They are to `view`. This means `inputContainerView` and `view` have to be in the same view hierarchy before the constraints can be activated.

Comment: i did     page.view.addSubview(inputContainerView)

Comment: Yes, you did, but you did it *after* trying to activate constraints, *and* you didn't add `page.view` to the view hierarchy that contains `view`.